# Alias Columns Returned by a Stored Procedure [SQL Server 2008]

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, alias

I'm not super familiar with stored procedures in general and SQL Server/T-SQL specifically. I'm wondering if there is a way to alias or rename the columns returned by a stored procedure without modifying the stored procedure itself.

Here is the stored procedure call I have now.

```
EXEC sp_GetNearbyLocations 38.858907, -77.261358
```

It returns records with the following columns:

```
State
Zip
Phone
StartDate
Directions
Hours
Latitude
Longitude
Distance
```

However I'd like them to be all lowercase and not camel cased. Sadly, I do not control the stored procedure so I cannot change it, just my call to it. Is this possible in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: 2008, I just updated my question to specify this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If SQL Server 2012 you can use the [`WITH RESULT SETS`](http://www.mytechmantra.com/LearnSQLServer/With-Result-Set-Feature-SQL-Server-2012.html) feature.

Otherwise this isn't possible it would require you to insert the results into some kind of intermediate temporary table then select from that.

(You could do this without creating the temp table explicitly by using [`OPEN ROWSET`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/12745/3690) however)

Comment: Looks like just what I need however I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2. :-( I'll update my post to specify this.

Comment: Still useful 9 years later. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own proc that simply calls the other one, aliases the columns and returns  that.

On a side note - why does the case of the column names matter to you?

Comment: Long story short, I'm writing a PHP backend that accesses this SQL Server DB and provides the data to a web frontend via AJAX. The JS code expects the field names to be in a certain form and case. It would be nice to not have to update the JS code or add PHP code that changes the names of the fields.